# Problems loading a package

Tags: package

I am attempting to load package  "parameters"
install.packages appropriately installed it.

library(parameters) resulted in this error:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘parameters’:
object ‘format_bf’ is not exported by 'namespace:insight'

I updated all the packages.

Any ideas?

Garry

Answer (score 0):

I found this post by searching for the same error. After installing the `insight` package and restarting R, the `parameters` package loaded with no issues. I'm not sure which of the two (`insight` or restart) fixed the problem.